# How to call an attribute from the same model for a validation with ember-cp-validation

Tags: validation, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-cp-validations

is there a way to call an attribute from the same model? Because I want to use an attribute, from model/code.js, to calculate the validator of an other attribute from the same file. I'll show you with example.

```js
//model/code.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';
import {validator, buildValidations} from 'ember-cp-validations';

const CardValidations = buildValidations(
    {
      cardId: {
            validators: [
                validator('presence', true),
                validator('length', {
                    // here instead of 10, I want to use nbBits
                    max: 10
                       
                }
            ]
        }
    }
);

export default Credential.extend(CardValidations, {
    cardId: DS.attr('string'),
    nbBits: DS.attr('number'),

    displayIdentifier: Ember.computed.alias('cardId'),
});
```

So as you can see, I want to call **nbBits**, to have a specific validation for **cardId**.
Does somebody know the methods or give me a tips? Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is described in the official [documentation](http://offirgolan.github.io/ember-cp-validations/docs/modules/Advanced.html#computed-options) of *ember-cp-validations* as follows:

```
const Validations = buildValidations({
  username: validator('length', {
    disabled: Ember.computed.not('model.meta.username.isEnabled'),
    min: Ember.computed.readOnly('model.meta.username.minLength'),
    max: Ember.computed.readOnly('model.meta.username.maxLength'),
    description: Ember.computed(function() {
      // CPs have access to the model and attribute
      return this.get('model').generateDescription(this.get('attribute'));
    }).volatile() // Disable caching and force recompute on every get call
  })
});
```

Your yet simpler case would look like this:

```
const CardValidations = buildValidations(
    {
      cardId: {
            validators: [
                validator('presence', true),
                validator('length', {
                    // here instead of 10, I want to use nbBits
                    max: Ember.computed.readOnly('model.nbBits')
                }
            ]
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Ah my bad, I didn't know about computed.readOnly, should have searched deeper, I tought that it has the same behavior than computed.not, which didn't work here. But thank you!

Comment: do you have any idea if can use the `Ember.computed.readOnly('model.nbBits')` to make calculus? like  `max: Ember.computed.readOnly('model.nbBits')  * 2`, right now it doesn't work because it's an ember object, but maybe you know how to do it?

Comment: It's a standard computed property use case, this should work just fine: 
`max: Ember.computed('model.nbBits', function(){
return parseInt(Ember.get(this, 'model.nbBits')) * 2;
})` ?

Comment: It work perfectly fine for me thank you, I tried with a function, but it didn't work, I called the element in a bad way.